# Select more tables using $query = mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

Can I select more tables using this?

```
$table = "users";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, smalltitle, FROM $table ORDER BY date DESC");
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($query))
{  
echo'<div id="title"> ';
    echo'<p>'.$result['title'].'</p>';
echo'</div>';

echo'<div id="name"> ';
    echo'<p>'.$result['name'].'</p>';
echo'</div>';
}
```

I want title/smalltitle from table "users" and name/text from table "gmsg"

Comment: use join in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with JOIN. Documentation for use JOIN in Mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
             ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query -

```
"SELECT users.title, users.smalltitle, gmsg.name FROM users, gmsg $where_condition ORDER BY users.date DESC"
```

`$where_condition` would be the condtion to match `users` & `gmsg` like -

```
$where_condition = "users.id = gmsg.user_id"; //Or whatever it is
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = "users";
$table2 = "gmsg";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.title, a.smalltitle, b.name, b.text FROM $table a, $table2 b ORDER BY a.date DESC");
```

Comment: a. means $table field and b. means $table2 fields